# Dial a number from saved contacts

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I want to dial a number from my saved contacts.I have following code.Is it Correct?

My code:

```
Button okButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ok_Button);
okButton.setOnCLickListener(new View.OnCLickListener() {
public void onCLick(View V){
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("Content//Contats/people");
setResult(RESULT_OK,result);
finish();
}
});
```

Comment: are you getting output ?

Comment: if you get the number then u should just pass the number in "Uri.parse(number)"